# How to write a doc that's incomplete / failed intentionally?

Tags: rust

I know one of the main Rust feature is built-in documentation testing. You can write any comment like this and it will be available on generated documentation. But how do you create a comment that incomplete / cannot run  ?

````
    /// ## Foo Function 
    /// Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    /// Duis eleifend at dolor auctor maximus. Vestibulum 
    /// ### How to use
    /// ```
    /// use my_app::Item; // how to skip testing this part ?
    /// Item::map_from_doc(&foo) <---- this error on test since I do not declare `foo` 
    /// ```
    pub fn foo_func(doc: &str) -> Result<Self, ItemError> {...}
````

I do not want to write the entire code for `foo` variable. I just want to give user a simple explanation about the function usage. I think that there should be a way to skip document testing on this part.

So  far I can only found about hiding parts of the code, which means that I need to write the complete example code and hide some of it. https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustdoc/documentation-tests.html

How to write a doc that's incomplete / failed intentionally ?

Comment: A better solution, usually, is to write the complete code but to hide the not interesting parts using `#`. This way you ensure the code is still tested and stays up to date with changes but doesn't clutter the doc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Down the page you linked is the [Attributes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustdoc/documentation-tests.html#attributes) section, which documents various directives you can use to configure non-standard / "abnormal" behaviour:

> ````
> /// ```ignore
> /// fn foo() {
> /// ```
> ````
>
> The `ignore` directive tells Rust to ignore your code. This is almost never what you want, as it's the most generic. Instead, consider annotating it with `text` if it's not code, or using `#`s to get a working example that only shows the part you care about.

I'm not going to copy the whole section, you can go read it, but the other useful values listed there are:

- `should_panic` tells rustdoc that the code should compile correctly, but not actually pass as a test.
- The `no_run` attribute will compile your code, but not run it. This is important for examples such as "Here's how to retrieve a web page," which you would want to ensure compiles, but might be run in a test environment that has no network access.
- `compile_fail` tells rustdoc that the compilation should fail. If it compiles, then the test will fail.
- `edition2018` tells rustdoc that the code sample should be compiled using the 2018 edition of Rust. Similarly, you can specify `edition2015` to compile the code with the 2015 edition.

In your case, `ignore` is probably the best attribute. Technically you could use `compile_fail` but you're not actually trying to demonstrate or assert a compilation failure so it feels like an over-specification *to me*.

Comment: oh yeah... my bad, I missed it